# nginx proxy_pass only works locally

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx

I set up a nodejs application on port 8082 and a nginx-webserver with those configurations:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        access_log \logs\access.log;
        location / {
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }
    }
}
```

in the nginx.conf file. The machine is a windows server 2008.
I control it with remote deskop, so i can check whether i can
ggo to the url mydomain.com and it works on that machine so far - the nodejs
app works fine.
**On any other machine i cannot get to the mydomain.com url**, i.e. i get "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT", but i can go to the ipadress on port 8082 and it works fine as well. I have the mydomain.com domain pointed to that ipadress and there is no hosts entry in system32/drivers/etc on the server as well

## edit:

problem was the firewall, it was set up for the IIS, not for nginx - so all incoming requests got blocked